# run method of a list of instances

Tags: python, multithreading, list, multiprocessing

I was trying to run a method of a list of instances but do not know how to except sequentially run them.

I have a list of instance of the same object:

```
class myclass(object):
   def __init__(xxx):
      ...
   def method(a, b):
      do something using a and b, 
      a and b will not be modified, 
      also no return value.
```

For each instance in the list `mylist`, I want to do `mylist[i].method(a,b)`.

Can I do this more efficiently except sequentially run them. 
Note that `a` and `b` are not global but need to be passed.

Comment: Use a `for` loop

Comment: @PatrickHaugh "Can I do this more efficiently **except sequentially** run them"

Comment: Since `mylist[i].method(a,b)` is slow, could be better not using for loop?

Comment: @fdafdsjflasdjlfas Use threads. `ThreadPool.map` is a good candidate.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full code, but this seems like a decent target for parallelization. With multiprocessing you could get a speedup proportional to the number of CPU cores available. If you're thinking "OK, so how do I integrate multiprocessing here?", again, that's hard to say without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the details you provided the easiest approach may be to create a wrapper function that will allow the usage of `ThreadPool.map`.

Since you mentioned that `a` and `b` won't be modified I used them as "global scope" variables. If they aren't you will need to find another way to pass them to each thread, perhaps by using `.apply` that allows you to pass arbitrary arguments to the executed function.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

a, b = 1, 2

class A:
    def method(self, a, b):
        print(a, b)

def wrapper(a_object):
    a_object.method(a, b)

objects = [A() for _ in range(5)]

pool = ThreadPool()  # with no arguments this will create N threads,
                     # N being the number of CPUs that Python detects.
pool.map(wrapper, objects)
#  1 2
#  1 2
#  1 2
#  1 2
#  1 2
```

Comment: Would this utilize multiple CPU or can I utilize multiple CPU

Comment: @fdafdsjflasdjlfas Yes. See the comment I wrote in the code, and you can also read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: could you please give an example how to pass `a` and `b` if they are not `global` but need to pass them?

Comment: @fdafdsjflasdjlfas See the usage of `apply` here https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: How about `map(wrapper, zip(objects, itertools.repeat((a,b))))`?